# How to show that for all positive rationals $r>s$ and $a>1$ that $ \frac{1}{r}(a^r-1)>\frac{1}{s}(a^s-1)$?

Tags: inequality

I've attempted a three part question to show that for all rationals $r>s$ and $a>1$ that $ \frac{1}{r}(a^r-1)>\frac{1}{s}(a^s-1)$.

i) Show that $\frac{a^m+a^{m-1}+...+1}{m+1}>\frac{a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}+...+1}{m}$ for all integers $m>0$

ii) Show for positive integers $n>m$ than $ \frac{1}{n}(a^n-1)>\frac{1}{m}(a^m-1)$

iii) Show that for all positive rationals $r>s$ that $ \frac{1}{r}(a^r-1)>\frac{1}{s}(a^s-1)$.

For i) I did:

$LHS-RHS=\frac{a^m+a^{m-1}+...+1}{m+1}-\frac{a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}+...+1}{m}$
$=\frac{ma^m-a^{m-1}-a^{m-2}-...-1}{m(m+1)}$
$>\frac{ma^m-a^{m}-a^{m}-...-a^m}{m(m+1)}$
$=0$ Hence proven

For ii) Take the proven identity, use the geometric series formula for the top and then let $m+1=n$ (which satisfies the condition as since $n$ and $m$ are integers, $n>m$ means $n≥m+1$)

Now for iii) I am not sure how to do this, I have no idea how I can change the inequality conditions without starting from scratch, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)={1\over r}(x^r-1)-{1\over s}(x^s-1).$ Then $f(1)=0$ and
$$f'(x)=x^{r-1}-x^{s-1}>0,\qquad x>1.$$ Hence the function $f$ is strictly increasing in the interval $[1,\infty).$ Therefore $f(x)>0$ for $x>1.$

If the original intension was not use differential calculus the solution could be as follows. I take for granted that the conclusion holds for natural numbers $n>m,$ as shown by ***Quippy***. Assume
$${p\over q}>{r\over s},\qquad p,q,r,s\in \mathbb{N}.$$
Then $ps>qr.$ Let $b=a^{1/(qs)}.$ Therefore
$${1\over ps}[b^{ps}-1]> {1\over qr}[b^{qr}-1].$$
Multiplying both sides by $qs$ gives
$${q\over p}[a^{p/q}-1]>{s\over r}[a^{s/r}-1]$$